# Como obter o endereço IP a partir da saída XML do nmap com um "vendor" específico utilizando ElementTree? no Python

Tags: python, xml

Utilizando a saída XML do [nmap](http://nmap.org/) para as máquinas virtuais alcançáveis, rodando na mesma máquina hóspede - obtida com `nmap -oX output.xml -sP 192.168.2.*`, gostaria de obter o endereço IP de cada máquina cujo atributo "vendor" seja `QEMU Virtual NIC`. Escolhi usar a [API XML ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml-tree-and-elements) para fazê-lo, mas estou tendo dificuldades para isolar os elementos **host** com os elementos **address** especificados.

Segue um trecho da saída XML a ser utilizada:

```
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
<address addr="192.168.2.93" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="52:54:00:E2:17:31" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="1023" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
<address addr="192.168.2.96" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="52:54:00:45:86:8A" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="155" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
<address addr="192.168.2.103" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="52:54:00:61:7A:E5" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="391" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>
```

Utilizando o comando `findall` e a sintaxe `XPath` abaixo, foi possível encontrar os elementos que possuem o atributo "vendor" desejado:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('output.xml')
tree.findall("./host/address/[@vendor='QEMU Virtual NIC']")
```

Porém, o que realmente quero, são os elementos **host** que contêm os elementos **address** encontrados acima, de forma que eu possa encontrar os outros sub-elementos de tipo "ipv4" para o mesmo host e assim, conseguir seu endereço IP. Alguém pode me ajudar a conseguir isto usando *XPath* e *ElementTree*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma mais simples de obter o resultado desejado seria a seguinte expressão, a qual resultou [desta outra outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22312105/1007502) no site em inglês. Reproduzo-a aqui no site em português, pois pode ser útil para alguém que não domine o inglês:

```
[i.get('addr') for i in tree.findall(
...     './host/address[@vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"]/../address[@addrtype="ipv4"]')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Não há um meio direto de se encontrar ancestrais através do `ElementTree`, mas [essa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170610/520779) mostra meios de se contornar isso, por exemplo:

```
parent_map = {c:p for p in tree.iter() for c in p}
```

ou (para versões de Python que não suportam dict comprehension):

```
parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p)
```

A partir daí você consegue achar os `host`s a partir dos `address`es retornados:

```
[parent_map[x] for x in tree.findall("./host/address/[@vendor='QEMU VirtualNIC']")]
```

Se necessário, você pode colocar os resultados num `set` (caso o mesmo `host` possa possuir mais de um endereço que se encaixe no filtro).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @mgibsonbr, mas na pergunta semelhante que fiz no site em inglês me responderam pouco tempo atrás com uma forma em que se pode andar "para cima" na hierarquia utilizando "..", veja: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22312105/1007502

Comment: @Claudio Hm, ok. Não sabia ao certo o quanto de XPath o ElementTree dava suporte, mas se ele permite `..` então é tranquilo.

Comment: Sim... é meu primeiro contato com isso no Python então nem sonhava que era possível também, mas acabei achando mais simples que o parent_map ai, é um pouco "criptico" não? hehe..